# Spring : How to remove localhost from url

Tags: java, spring, url

I am working on some project for that using spring 3.2.0. Whenever I run project it looks like

http://IpAddressWithPortNo.com/myprojectName.com/

> IpAddressWithPortNo = localhost : 8080

I want to hide localhost:8080 or ip address.

Is there any method available to map this ip to my project?

http://myprojectName.com

I am using apache tomcat 7.0 and fedora 17.

Comment: Hide from where? The browser address bar? No way. The address bar shows the address. The real one.

Comment: Sir JB Nizet ... lets say  ip address is - 10.208.11.201 i want to map my project name with this ip. if one can type project name then he ll see home page of project. like. http://projectname.com but now actually wat happen its looks like http://localhost:8080/projectname.com i want to avoid this part.

Comment: Sir Jens ... I am using Fedora 17 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution doesn't involve configuring Spring, but the **hosts** file of your operating system. On Ubuntu, it is found at /etc/hosts, I'm not sure if its the same for Fedora, but it should be.

You just need to add a line in the hosts file that looks like the following:

```
127.0.0.1    myprojectName.com
```

That's it. You then access the *myprojectName.com* address in your browser and it will look at your localhost, behind the scenes.

The above solution works if you only need name resolution for your local machine.

If you'd like to expand to your local or external network, the answer is less trivial:

- for your local network, you need to register a custom domain on your network DNS server (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69723/how-can-i-configure-my-server-so-that-my-domain-points-to-it) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69723/how-can-i-configure-my-server-so-that-my-domain-points-to-it) for more information); if you have a network administrator, direct this requirement to him, explaining that you want to expose your local ip through a custom domain name
- if you want to expose this name to the entire internet, you have to register the custom domain to a DNS registration service (you can find free DNS services as well, unfortunately I haven't used any lately and dyndns.org doesn't provide free dns service anymore, try searching *free dns service* on google and lookup some reviews)

Answer (score 0):

The :8080 will go if you configure Tomcat to respond on port 80, or https on port 443.
You can use any host name that resolves to your network address. For instance if your machine name on the local network is athena.mycompany.com then http://athena.mycompany.com/myProjectName should work fine - but only within the local network.

To get to http://myprojectName.com you will need to configure a firewall/router to forward an incoming request (presumably from the Internet) to your machine. Internal access will likely not resolve this URL.

Gabriel has just posted an answer that should work from your machine, but other machines within your intranet would also require entries to map that name to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

For doing exactly what you want, you need to configure apache tomcat to listen on port 80 and tell your operating system that myproject.com resolves to localhost.

To resolve myproject.com to localhost, add the following to your /etc/hosts file:
    127.0.0.1    myproject.com

To change the port number to 80, open  /usr/share/tomcat7/confserver.xml or /etc/tomcat7/server.xml (whichever applies to your system) and change Connector port = 8080 to Connector port = 80.